# No numlock in screen?

Tags: bash, debian, gnu-screen, putty, numlock

I am using a laptop and Putty on a Windows system.

When I connect to my Debian Squeeze server in Bash environment, I can use the "Pos1/Home" or "End" (at the numlock part of the keyboard) to navigate through the commandline I am just writing.

However, when I create a "subshell" using `screen`, I cannot use Pos1/Home or End anymore. Pressing Num-Lock does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason why it didn't work.

In the PuTTy configuration I had to change the session settings as follows:

**Connection -> Data -> Terminal details -> Terminal-type string**

The value was: **xterm**
I changed it to **linux**

Now I can use the Home+End keys in Bash and in Screen as well.

`echo $TERM` will show `linux` outside screen and `screen.linux` inside screen.

---

**UPDATE 23 Oct 2018**

I have found a much easier solution!

Just start screen with this command:

`TERM=linux screen`

or put this line in your **~/.bashrc** :

`alias screen='TERM=linux screen'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem can probably be fixed by setting the `$TERM` variable in screen. Try adding `term screen-256color` to `~/.screenrc`.

If this does not work, try adding `termcapinfo xterm ks@:ke@' to`~/.screenrc` as well. This might break some other keys so you should test it thoroughly.

Comment: Setting that environment variable in `~/.screenrc` or launching `screen -T screen-256color` does not help.
Ctrl+V does not work in Putty. But it does work if I perform the keystroke at the actual machine (I am testing on a VM now).
Home/End does always work in `screen` when I am at the virtual machine, but does not work when I do the same in Putty+Screen.

Comment: Ctrl+V at the virtual machine showed the keys `^[[1~` and `^[[4~` . Adding these 2 keys in `~/.inputrc` does not help. Probably the keycodes passed through PuTTy are different. (However, Putty+Bash does work, but Putty+Screen does not work!)
Is it correct entering `"^[[1~": begin-of-line` in `~/.inputrc` or do I need to replace `^` with `\e` or `[[` with `[`? (I tried various)

Comment: Oh, I somehow completely ignored the part of the question that mentioned you are doing this through putty. I found a working solution, at least one that works on my computer using Putty to SSH to an Arch Linux machine. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But alas, it does not work - the screen just blinks when I press the Home key. I have changed `~/.screenrc` to: `term linux` . But that does not work. When I execute `screen` and (inside screen) `echo $TERM` I will get `screen-256color` . If I then enter `TERM=linux` inside screen, it will work. How can I tell screen to do that automatically at each start?

Comment: I have just found the solution. I changed the terminal type in PuTTy from xterm to linux. This affects both, bash and screen. Thank you all the same for taking time to help me. :-) Your hint with the TERM setting was important to find the problem.